# Cumulative count to group in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, row-number

I have a query that returns a list of dates, now what I want to achieve is to group them and identify the grouping with a null.

Example Query:

```
SELECT  *,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Date1.Date1 ORDER BY Date1.Date1) as rwnumber
FROM Date1
    LEFT JOIN Date2
        ON Date1.Date1= Date2.Date1
```

OUTPUT:

```
ID     DATE1         DATE2         rwnumber
1    06-10-2019    06-10-2019         1
1    06-25-2019    06-25-2019         1
1    07-10-2019    NULL               1
1    07-25-2019    07-25-2019         1    
1    08-10-2019    08-10-2019         1
```

What I want to achieve is this desired OUTPUT:

```
ID     DATE1         DATE2         rwnumber
1    06-10-2019    06-10-2019         1
1    06-25-2019    06-25-2019         1
1    07-10-2019    NULL               2 or 0
1    07-25-2019    07-25-2019         3    
1    08-10-2019    08-10-2019         3
```

So I can group this dates to two group.

Other Example Output:

```
ID     DATE1         DATE2         rwnumber
1    06-10-2019    06-10-2019        group 1
1    06-25-2019    NULL               
1    07-10-2019    07-10-2019        group 2      
1    07-25-2019    07-25-2019        group 2    
1    08-10-2019    08-10-2019        group 2

ID     DATE1         DATE2         rwnumber
1    06-10-2019    06-10-2019        group 1
1    06-25-2019    06-25-2019        group 1               
1    07-10-2019    07-10-2019        group 1      
1    07-25-2019    NULL                  
1    08-10-2019    08-10-2019        group 2
```

Comment: why the 2 dates rownmber are 3?

Comment: If there is no null value then the result of query will be 1 group but if there is a null value then it will group the result before or after the null value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to want a cumulative count of `NULL` values:

```
select t.*,
       (case when date2 is null then 0
             else 1 + sum(case when date2 is null then 1 else 0 end) over (order by date1)
        end) as grouping
from t;
```

This returns grouping values of 1, 2, 3 and so on for the groups.  The `NULL` values all have a value of `0`.  This seems quite consistent with what you want to do.

Comment: I have done this by doing a loop and you just do it by a simple select. huhuhu Thank you sir.

Answer (score 2):

`RANK` and  `DENSE_RANK` are deterministic in this case, all rows with the same value for both the ordering and partitioning columns will end up with an equal result, whereas `ROW_NUMBER` will arbitrarily (non deterministically) assign an incrementing result to the tied rows.

you shouldn't be using `ROW_NUMBER()`,

- use `DENSE_RANK()` instead
- remove `PARTITION BY`

query,

```
    WITH T(ID, Date1)
         AS (SELECT 1,'06-10-2019' UNION ALL
             SELECT 1,'06-25-2019' UNION ALL
             SELECT 1,'07-10-2019' UNION ALL
             SELECT 1,'07-25-2019' UNION ALL
             SELECT 1,'08-10-2019')
    SELECT *,            
           DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY Month(Date1)) AS 'DENSE_RANK'
    FROM   T
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/61549)

Comment: Hello sir, thank you for answering my question. According to your answer this will be group by month but if you will look in my desired output 7/25/2019 and 8/10/2019 is group as one and they are different month.

Comment: How you are framing group here

Comment: If there is a null row then the next row after null will be the 2nd group.

Comment: I have added few other examples of the grouping. Thanks sir.